# android activity always on top

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest

There are 2 activities: A and B
if activity A is started then it will be always on top of activity B (if B exist)
if B is started and A is in foreground then B will go right under A
if A is going in background or is closed then(if B exist) B will be shown

each activity is running in its own task

In other words is there a simple way to start an activity right under the current activity so when that close then it will be shown

what is the simplest way to do this using manifest flags preferably

Comment: I think you have to use Fragment instead of activity.

Comment: no, there must be simple way

Comment: I think, You have to implement the `APPLICATION class` in order to implement this, The logic could be : `Your application class will hold the record that which activity is displaying currently, and Do according to that situation`

Comment: `if B is started and A is in foreground then B will go right under A` you can not send activity(B) behind A because A is now in foreground and you have no activity instance of B.

Comment: I want to say that when you start B it will not go in the foreground

Answer (score 0):

Start A inside new Task stack. Read docs for `Intent`.

Inside `onCreate` of A check Intent and open B.

Now you have new stack where B is above A, however and A and B were used before.